# JOOQ plugin for latest JOOQ library in gradle project

Tags: gradle, jooq

I have a problem with finding a working JOOQ plugin or its configuring for latest JOOQ library in my java gradle project.

I have found the following plugins:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-codegen-gradle

This doesn't work for me due to error message:

```
Could not find any version that matches org.jooq:jooq-codegen-gradle:latest.integration.
Searched in the following locations:
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq-codegen-gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq-codegen-gradle/
```

- https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-jooq-plugin

That is working only for JOOQ 3.2.2(latest 3.4.2 is not working). If I set it up to 3.4.2, jooqGenerate executes successfully but data fetching invokes error message:

```
Error:(12, 8) java: org.jooq.generated.tables.records.PersonsRecord is not abstract and does not override abstract method values(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in org.jooq.Record3
```

What i do wrong?

That is my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jooq'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.4.2'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.4.2'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.4.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-jooq-plugin:+'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:+'
    }
}

jooq {
    jdbc {
        url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306'
        driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        user 'admin'
        passwoed 'xxx'
    }
    generator {
        database {
            name 'org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
            inputSchema 'test_db'
            includes '.*'
        }
    }
}
```

App.class where I do data fetch:

```
import static org.jooq.generated.Tables.PERSONS;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db","admin","xxx")){
            DSLContext create = DSL.using(c, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

            for(PersonsRecord personsRecord : create.selectFrom(PERSONS).fetch()) {
                System.out.println(personsRecord
                );
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Updated build.gradle file for https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:+'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:+'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:+'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-meta:+'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:+'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:+'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jooq {
    jdbc {
        url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306'
        driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        user 'admin'
        password 'xxx'
    }
    generator {
        database {
            name 'org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
            inputSchema 'test_db'
            includes '.*'
        }
        generate {
            daos true
            classes false
        }
    }
}
```

**Working gradle script:**

```
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:1.0.5'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:+'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:+'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:+'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}


jooq {
    sample(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db'
            user = 'admin'
            password = 'qwerty123'
            schema = 'test_db'
        }
        generator {
            name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
            strategy {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
            }
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
                inputSchema = 'test_db'
            }
            generate {
                daos = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'org.homemade.warehouse.db'
                directory = 'src/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Lukas Eder and Etienne Studer, plugin is really working now!

Comment: Could You prepare a minimal working example on GitHub?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the build.gradle file that you provide for the Gradle plugin 'nu.studer.jooq', you must use the equal sign for assigning configuration values:

Instead of:

```
jdbc {
    url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306'
    ....
}
```

It should be:

```
jdbc {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306'
    ....
}
```

If you use the latest version of the plugin (1.0.5), you must give your configuration a name (since you can define multiple configurations) and define to which source set the generated sources are added:

```
jooq {
    sample(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

See also https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#configuration

If you want to enforce the plugin to use a specific version of jOOQ, you can do it like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...

    configurations.classpath {
        resolutionStrategy {
            forcedModules = [
                'org.jooq:jooq:3.4.1',
                'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.4.1',
                'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.4.1'
            ]     
        }
    }
}
```

See also https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#custom-jooq-version

Comment: Thanks, it is realy working. My problem was in wrong configuration, inattentive=)

Comment: @user1376885: This shows that sometimes, one should sit down and study the actual problem rather than choosing the path of least resistance (as in my answer) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're seeing:

> Error:(12, 8) java: org.jooq.generated.tables.records.PersonsRecord is not abstract and does not override abstract method values(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in org.jooq.Record3

Is really due to an `@Override` annotation being put on a method that is implemented from an interface, not from an abstract class. This usage of the `@Override` annotation is available only from Java 6 onwards. You should probably switch to using

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
```

An alternative jOOQ/Gradle plugin, which might be a bit easier to use and more up to date can also be found her:

- https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin

#### Standalone code generator

Note that you do not need to use any Gradle plugin to make use of jOOQ's standalone code generator, which can be provided with programmatic configuration, as can be seen in the examples:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-codegen-gradle

For instance:

```groovy
// Configure the Java plugin and the dependencies
// ----------------------------------------------
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT'

    runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.177'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.177'
    }
}


task generate << {

    // Use your favourite XML builder to construct the code generation 
    // configuration file
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
    .configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.4.0.xsd') {
        jdbc() {
            driver('org.h2.Driver')
            url('jdbc:h2:~/test-gradle')
            user('sa')
            password('')
        }
        generator() {
            database() {
            }
            generate() {
            }
            target() {
                packageName('org.jooq.example.gradle.db')
                directory('src/main/java')
            }
        }
    }

    // Run the code generator
    // ----------------------
    org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(
        javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(
            new StringReader(writer.toString()), 
            org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration.class
        )
    )
}
```

And then run the above with

```
gradle generate
```

Comment: Setting SourceCompability version to 1.6 or higher doesn't help me for ben-manes plugin. I'm trying to use your alternative way, which  I have already tried in some day but still have troubles with the plugin configuration I quess(I have updated my build.gradle file for this alternative plugin). Could you take me some tips why gradle doesn't understand jdbc(mysql server is up, libraries downloaded and added to project by gradle)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, unfortunately. But we're currently working on a little Gradle tutorial with jOOQ's standalone code generator. That would remove the need for a third-party plugin, and could be fully supported by Data Geekery. I'll update my answer in a bit...

Comment: Thanks again, it helps me. Now I can generate whatever I want with latsj jooq version. One smal remark - no such codegen version 'xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.5.0.xsd'. Latest is 3.4.

Comment: I hvae only one question, as I see code generation executes everytime when you run this script. It can be clean task or whatever else, how can I separate execution of code generation? Otherwise it looks a bit strange and not clean -  some kind of code in the build.gradle script. How can I do my script more pretty and clean?

Comment: @user1376885: Just wrap that part in a task, I guess...? I'm sorry, I'm not that much of a Gradle expert myself, so I kind of chose the path of least resistance here. Probably someone with more experience can provide you with a better answer...

Comment: Your answers help me, now it is separate task to generate code, it works with latest jooq, it is cool. I only cannot understand one thing if it so easy to use jooq why plugins, which should just improves configuration steps, works incorrectly. That's strange=) But thank you, you help me.

Comment: @user1376885: I'm talking with Etienne Studer. We'll figure it out, eventually. He might show up here to provide you with answers...